# Check for current version of daily build for automated install?

Tags: c#

Forgive me if this has already been asked, but I'm new to C# and am currently working on a side application to automate the install of the product that I test.  My question is: Is it possible to check a folder location on the build server and pick up the most current build without having to manually stipulate what the location/build number is?  I'm looking to make this as automated as possible and would like for the application to automatically execute the install.  Forgive me if this is a trivial question, I just don't want to invest too much time on a feature that is either not possible or would take too long to implement.  Thanks in advance!

/matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should investigate [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx).  Unless you're doing strange things (like ActiveX controls etc) then ClickOnce has all the abilities you've asked for in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I will look into that and see if it will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Failing that simply have your automated build copy the outputs to a "latest" folder.  We have our MSI's copied there, then you just use Windows scheduled tasks every few minutes to see if a new version is there.  If it is you uninstall old, copy new MSI locally and install new with batch files.

Its simple and works well for some circumstances.

Comment: The daily build is already put out into a folder, it's just that everyday there's an additional folder within there (it's a product with multiple installers).  So your suggestion could work.  Couldn't I give it a baseline build number and have it ping the folder and look for a build in an increment of 1 greater than the current build? Or base it off the currently installed build and increment each day off that?

Comment: I'm sure you could.  
Our version numbers are not that predictable for a given folder structure so we use the folder called "latest" to avoid having to work it out.  (If a build fails for example a version number could be skipped).
The copy operation copies to the versioned folder (e.g. 1.0.0.1) and also to a special folder called "Latest".  We then just check the folder called latest for changes.
As the copy to the "latest" folder is the last thing in the build script we know it was a good build.